# JavaScript regex for numbers with brackets and commas

Tags: javascript, regex

I gave the input `(123,456.12)` and my output should be `-123456.12`. But its coming as just `-123`.
I used the expression:

```
enteredValue = window.event.srcElement.value.replace(/^[-(]\D*([\d.]+).*$/gm, '-$1')
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't include comma:

```
.replace(/^[-(]\D*([\d,.]+).*$/gm, '-$1')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4bKJp/

Comment: I tried ..but it dint work.I again got the same output as -123.Not sure why its not working ..

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 var str = "(123,456.12)".replace( /[(),]/g, "" );
 var num = -Number( str );
```

Comment: Or maybe something more like `var num = -Number(str);`